# Ifchanged if not null

Tags: django

I have the following logic in my template:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    {% ifchanged task.shared_task_id %}
        <tr>{{ task }}</tr>
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I want to ignore the `ifchanged` tag if the `shared_task_id` is None. Something like:

```
{% ifchanged task.shared_task_id or if task.shared_task_id == None %}
    <tr>{{ task }}</tr>
{% endifchanged %}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question. In your question it seems you don't want to print a task if it's id is `None`, but in your own answer it seems you always want to print a task if it's id is `None`, even if it's not changed?

Comment: @knbk thanks, I updated the code in my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (edited with Hieu's fix):

```
{% ifchanged task.shared_task_id %}
    <tr>{{ task }}</tr>
{% else %}
    {% if not task.shared_task_id %}
        <tr>{{ task }}</tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endifchanged %}
```

Not really adhering to the DRY principle, but way less hackish that what you're using now. Django's template language is not really meant for advanced logic, so I don't think there are any better solutions.

If you need to print a lot of stuff instead of just `{{ task }}`, I think the best way to not repeat yourself abundantly and ease the pain of updating your code is to use a separate template and use `{%include <other_template> %}`.

Comment: @David542 @knbk I don't think this will work well. 2 serial if statement would allow fall through. For example with list [1, None], on the 2nd iteration, the `task` will be printed twice.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this by a sort of hackish way in the model now:

```
{% ifchanged task.shared_task_id_or_random %}

# models.py
def shared_task_id_or_random(self):
    return self.shared_task_id or str(random.random())
```

Any better ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't have `and` and `or` logic in `{% ifchange %}`, you can always use 2 if blocks to achieve what you want:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    {% ifchanged task.shared_task_id %}
        <tr>{{ task }}</tr>
    {% else %}
        {% if task.shared_task_id == None %}
            <tr>{{ task }}</tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```